# Value in textarea doesn't get deleted in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> **I am having a problem where every time I try to delete the top-most checkbox, the value in textarea does not get deleted. Instead, the
> value in textarea gets passed down to the bottom component. Why is
> this happening and how can I solve this? For example, I have attached an imgur to the problem I am dealing with. If you look closely, every checkbox has a unique id attached to them. When I try to delete "Hello" for example, it doesn't get deleted but instead gets passed down to the bottom component. I've tried figuring this out but no luck. Please help me. **

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p057C.jpg

```
**PriorityLists.jsx**
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Priority } from "./Actions";




function PriorityLists(props) {
    const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [changeInput, setChangeInput] = useState(null);
  

    


    function check(e) {
        const id_to_be_deleted = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("unique_Key").value;
       
        if(!isChecked) {
            setChecked(true);
            props.addIds(isChecked, id_to_be_deleted);

        }

        else {
            setChecked(false);
            props.addIds(isChecked, id_to_be_deleted)
        }
    }
    

    return ( 
    <form key = {props.id}  >
       <div className = "input-group mb-3">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                <input unique_Key = {props.id}   onInput = {e=>   e.target.checked = isChecked} onClick={e=> check(e) } checked = {props.checked} id = "check-item" type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea id = {props.id} onChange = {e=>setChangeInput(e.target.value)} value = {changeInput}  class="form-control"  rows="1" name = {props.name}></textarea>
            <Priority/>
         </div>
   </form>
    )
}

export {PriorityLists};
```

---

```
**Tasks.jsx**
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Delete, Refresh, Add} from "../components/Actions";
import {Header} from "../components/Header";
import {PriorityLists} from "../components/PriorityLists";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';



function Task() {

    const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([]);
    const [idsToRefresh, setIdsToRefresh] = useState([]);
    const [filter_items, setFilterItems] = useState(false);
    const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(toDo[0] !== undefined) {
            setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
                return !ids.includes(item._Id);
            }))
        }


    }, [filter_items]);

    function addIds(checked, id_to_be_deleted) {
        if(!checked) {
            setIds((item)=> [...item, id_to_be_deleted]);
        }
        else {
            setIds(ids.filter(item=> {
                return item !== id_to_be_deleted;
            }))
        }
    }



    function addToDos() {
        const id = uuidv4();
        setToDo(toDo.concat({_Id: id, value:<PriorityLists id = {id} checked = {false} addIds = {addIds} />}));
        setIdsToRefresh(idsToRefresh.concat(id));
     
      
    }

  
    

    function refresh() {
        setToDo(toDo.filter(item=> {
            return !idsToRefresh.includes(item._Id);
        }))
    }



    return (
    <div className = "main-content">
        <div className = "container-fluid">
            <div className = "row underline">
                <div className= "col">
                    <div className = "row">
                    <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                        <Refresh _refresh = {refresh} />
                    </div>

                    <div className = "col-6 text-center">
                        <Header header ={"Tasks"}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className = "col-3 pt-2">
                        <button  className = "float-right">
                            <Delete setFilterItems = {setFilterItems} filter = {filter_items} />
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className = "row">
                <div className = "col">
                   {
                   toDo.map(item=> {
                       return (<div> 
                       <ul>
                           <li>{item.value} {item._Id}</li>
                         
                       </ul>
                       </div>)
                   })}
                   
                   
 
                    
                </div>
            </div>


            <div className = "row">
                
                <div className = "col pr-4">
        
                    <Add addToDos = {addToDos} />
                
                </div>
            </div>



        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    )
}

export default Task;
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you don't give proper keys when rendering an array of items. **Give them a unique key**. eg:

```
    toDo.map(item=> {
        return (<div key={item._Id}>
```

Then when deleting something, delete it via that key, not based on its position in the list.

Also look up what keys are and why they're important in React, particularly in regards to mutable lists

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I knew it was something related to the key but didn't know where it was happening.  I spent a week trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Ron no worries, glad it's all sorted :) if this answer solves your question please mark it as the correct answer (the tick below the downvote arrow)

Comment: Dude, Thank you so much, literally whole day wasted for me, , I missed this key Part thank youu